# How to make SoapUI json request work with german umlauts?

Tags: json, rest, character-encoding, soapui, mappingexception

We use SoapUI for many interfaces in our team project. We came across a problem with german special signs, called umlauts. When sending a POST request with Json body and a german umlaut, the we get `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`. It cannot be parsed with `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.

[image: SoapUI Json request]

But when sending the same request using POSTMAN, then it works like a charm.
[image: Postman Json request]

We use `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=utf-8"})` annotations and `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` header. But still no effect. Has anyone ever came across such a problem or know how to solve it? We cannot change the testing tool.

Comment: Just one addition to the comment from user3499394. That is what worked for me (thanks!), however when I set the same using:
"Content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8" directly in the headers of my request, it does not behave the same. The only thing that works is actually setting encoding via Properties tab. This must be a bug in SoapUI.
My version of SoapUI is 5.2.1.

Comment: @BorisGligorijević, same problem here with 5.3.0. Resolved also only with the Properties tab.

Comment: BTW, if you are looking for a mock service to return proper UTF-8, you will need to add "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8" to <Soap UI Home>\bin\<Soap UI Version>.vmoptions file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In SoapUI there is an additional property for setting the encoding of your request.

It is available under the tab `Request Properties`. 
`Property: Encoding`, `Value: UTF-8`.

Setting it as above solved our problem.