# how to use umlaut with spring api

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I have a problem with sending umlauts to Spring API. I want to post a following JSON:

```
{
 "username": "testümlaut",
 "firstName": "test",
 "lastName": "Test"
}
```

for this I have a following method start:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/User", method=RequestMethod.POST,
        produces={"application/json ; charset=utf-8"}
)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public @ResponseBody User postUser(@RequestBody User user) {      

    User user = userDao.addUser(user);

    return user;
  }
```

As you can see I do have a line:

```
produces={"application/json ; charset=utf-8"}
```

but it does not help. I get always an exception (0xfc is ü):

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@721e5ed1; line: 2, column: 19] (through reference chain: de.escosautomation.restserver.model.user.UserClone["username"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@721e5ed1; line: 2, column: 19] (through reference chain: de.escosautomation.restserver.model.user.UserClone["username"])
```

What can I also add to make it work?

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check a few options here:

- Encoding on your application server. For example on Tomcat, on all connectors make sure you have **URIEncoding** set to UTF-8. E.G.:

  `<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             connectionTimeout="20000"
             redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`
- As you send a    JSON, you need to have **both** consumes and
  produces set to    `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`
  (application/json;charset=UTF-8). E.G:

`@RequestMapping(value="/User", method=RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)`

- In **web.xml**:

  `<filter>
      <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>encoding</param-name>
          <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>`

Comment: done (i have a jetty server and do not know how to configure encoding as a property for all the requests). doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually I accept the answer of Yuri Yunikov.

But if someone is using SOAPui, don't forget to set the Encoding of request also there:
[like it is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151644/how-to-make-soapui-json-request-work-with-german-umlauts)